# how to make default x close winow in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a question almost every OS when shows user a window shows him "-" "a square" and "X" kivy by default makes "-" and square(button that changes window size) work normally but "X" does not close the window it only stops it from working is there a way to make it close the window instantly by shutting down the process

Comment: This sounds like a bug, what log output do you get when you click the X? Also, what operating system?

Comment: I am using windows and i got closing application but i want to make the app work for 3 systems(linux, mac and windows)